# rotate value given by javascraip

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm learning to code so I'm building a coin tossing app. I buit everything and I'm now trying to animate a coin...
my plan: get a random int (limited to  10 or 11) and, and multiply it by 180. THe result is the number of degrees the coin will rotate.

10 rotation, it comes back to head, 11 rotations, it flips to tails.

My problem: How do I feed this number of degrees back to css?

Can I use a js variable as a value for "transfor: rotateX('js var here')" in css?

I have no idea what jquerys are. I suppose i'll learn them soon, but not tonight. So if there is a way to do this without them, it would be great...

Thanks in advance for your help!!
ERIc

Comment: What is your current code without JavaScript setting the rotation?

Comment: I have no idea how to post code so it's higlited in blue. I see every body's code like this. I dont have much besides two round divs. first one is head. Second on, tails, is rotated 180deg. Both have 'backface-visibility:hidden".

Comment: I want to flip them 10 or 11 times depending on javascript's random choice. I fugured out how to change an element's style with JS. But I could'nt figure out how to rotate an element.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use a js variable as a value for "transform: rotateX('js var here')" in css?

No, but almost… What you could do is use a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) like so `transform: rotateX(var(--rotate))` and set the value of this variable using javascript like so `coin.style.setProperty('--rotate', rotate)` where `coin` is your coin node and `rotate` the value you want to pass (for example `1800deg` or `1980deg`).

```js
const coin = document.getElementById('coin');

document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener('click', evt => {
    const rotate = 180 * ((Math.random() < .5) ? 10 : 11);
  coin.style.setProperty('--rotate', `${rotate}deg`);
});

document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  coin.style.setProperty('--rotate', '');
});
```

```css
#coin {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #ffd300;
  border: 8px solid #ff8d00;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  transform: rotateX(var(--rotate, 0));
  transition: 4s;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="coin">H</div>
  <p>
    <button id="flip">Flip</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: oh! ok... I see! So when I press the "filp" button, JS returns the number of degrees to this css variable and activates the rotation. That seems doable... Thanks you so much! I had never heard of css variables.. And what is the easyest way to activate the rotation? I usually use .mydiv:active{transform...} can JS return the "active" value to an element?

Comment: By 'activate' do you mean trigger the rotation ? In this case I would say with a button. Listen to the click event on the button, once this event has been dispatch calculate the rotation and set the CSS variable. I've updated the snippet in the answer